# Конструкция через echo

Tags: php

Вопрос даже очень легкий, что не так со строкой?

```
$time= '$party_min - $min_now'. 'party_hour - $hour_now', '$party_day - $day_now', '$party_month - $month_now';
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Запятые не так со строкой (на точки замените)

Хотя рискну предположить, что вам надо что-то такое

```
$time= ($party_min - $min_now).', '.($party_hour - $hour_now).', '.($party_day - $day_now).', '.($party_month - $month_now);
```

Comment: 'party_hour - $hour_now'
->
    '$party_hour - $hour_now'

Comment: Sh4dow все прекрасно работает, спасибо